# Why does Trig Substitution need the substitution to be one-to-one?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

**From textbook:**

> $$\int f(x)\,dx = \int f(g(t))g'(t)\,dt$$
>   This kind of substitution is called *inverse substitution*.
>
> We can make this inverse substitution $x = a\sin \theta$ provided that it defines a one-to-one function. This can be accomplished by restricting $\theta$ to lie in the interval $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.
>   [Image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/si6Dm.jpg)

$\int f(x)\,dx$
$x = g(t) \longleftarrow$ Why does this need to be a  one-to-one function?
$\frac{dx}{dt} = g'(t)$
$dx = g'(t)\,dt$
$\int f(g(t))g'(t)\,dt$

I would assume $g(t)$ would only need to be differentiable.

Comment: I suppose the extreme example would be the substitution $x=0$.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and type out all images. This helps others find this post.

Comment: @Max  Oh I didn't think about that from a search perspective, I will next time.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Heh, that's real funny XD

Comment: @SimpleArt Actually it was meant seriously, see my comment to the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to think about it, is that the trig substitution is a transformation of the coordinate system.  If the the transformation is not $1-1$, then you have some part of the $x-$axis (and the $xy-$ plane) that is folded over on itself.

A less abstract way of thinking about it is to consider:

$\int_a^b f(x) dx$ where $f(x)>0 \;\forall x\in (a,b)$

Clearly, $\int_a^b f(x) dx>0$

But if our substition is not $1-1$ there exists the possibility that $g^{-1}(b) = g^{-1}(a),$ in which case if we proceed with the substitution.

$x = g(t), dx = g'(t) dt\\
\int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(b)} f(g(t))g'(t) dt = \int_{g^{-1}(a)}^{g^{-1}(a)} f(g(t))g'(t) dt = 0$

Creating a contradiction.

Comment: Of course if $g^{\prime}(c)\neq 0$ then $g$ will be injective in a nbh of $c$ so can be used to find the indefinite integral.

Comment: How did you turn $g^{-1}(b)$ into $g^{-1}(a)$ in the integral?

Comment: @A_for_Abacus if it is not $1$ to $1$, then there may exist some $a$ such that $g^{-1}(b)=g^{-1}(a)$.