# Integration by inverse substitution - some necessary condition(s)

Tags: integration, substitution

This image:
[image]
from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968875) says that inverse substitution requires the substitute to be one-to-one.

But whether $g$ is one-to-one or not, I thought one could write

$$ \int f(x)dx = \int f(g(t))g'(t)dt
\\
{\textit{or more precisely:}\hspace{12cm}}
\\
\int f(x)dx = \left(\int f(g(t))g'(t)dt\right)\circ g^{-1}
\\
{\textit{where }g^{-1}\textit{ is any right inverse of g}\hspace{9cm}}$$

though only if the range of $g$ (and its codomain for the right inverse to exist) equals the domain of $f$.

A comment to the linked question suggests considering $g(t) = 0$, but the range of that doesn't equal the domain of any reasonable $f$. The answer in the linked question says:

> ... consider:
>
> $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ where $f(x)>0 \;\forall x\in (a,b)$
>
> ... if our substition is not $1-1$ there exists the possibility that
>   $g^{-1}(b) = g^{-1}(a),$

which confuses me because, to me $g^{-1}(b) = g^{-1}(a)$ means $g$ is not well-defined if $a<b$.

Is everything in the linked question really as wrong as it seems to me?